# html textearea with multiple lines. Want to convert to php array, each line is one element of array

Tags: php, arrays

In textarea i type words, each in new line. Type a word, press Enter. Like this

```
first
second
third
```

Want to get php array like this

```
[0] => first
[1] => second
[2] => third
```

Tried

```
$arr_list_from_textarea = explode( PHP_EOL, $_POST['list_from_textarea'] );
```

But got

```
Array
(
[0] => first
second
third
)
```

What need to change? Instead of `PHP_EOL` something else?

`"\n"` works. But `'\n'` and `"\r\n"` do not work.

Comment: just try and play with it, trial and error, `"\r\n"`, `"\n"` not hard to try. and the double quotes wrapping it is important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use that constant. Use `"\n"` (use double quotes so the string is not treated literally, but the actual character).

`PHP_EOL` is used for writing files, etc so you can handily grab the platform specific end-of-line character. When handling user input, browsers are kind enough to always give you `\n` as the line separator.